# how to capture the Cookies in HttpQueryInfo using wininet c++

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, wininet

Currently I'm facing an issue in capturing the Cookies which is coming as part of response. I'm using *WinInet* for my connection.

After sending the request using `HttpSendRequest`, I'm using `HttpQueryInfo` to query the response in the below order

1. `HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE`
2. `HTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE`
3. `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE`
4. `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH`

Finally I'm reading body content using InternetReadFile.

Server has the loadbalance installed. all the response sent from LB has "*Set-Cookies*" enabled.

If I get any response without "Set-Cookies" in header then my code is reading the content successfully.
When there is "Set-Cookies" field in header then the issue comes. It is resulting out in "Header Not Found" when I query for "HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_TYPE"

**Below is the sample response header which is success**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 10:05:00 GMT
Content-Length: 107
Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8
Via: 1.1 TestServer:80 (Cisco-WSA/8.8.0-085)
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Below is the sample response header which is error out.**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: MYID=B3C5D2B2%2D0426%2D473F%2DACF6%2DF19BAC3F5A6C%3A%3A88757401; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 10:07:20 GMT
Content-Length: 277
Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8
Via: 1.1 TestServer:80 (Cisco-WSA/8.8.0-085)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Work around found, 
While querying the response header, if I add `HTTP_QUERY_COOKIE` in the sequence then the issue is getting resolved but I'm not sure on this is correct or not.

Can any one help me?

1. Why `SET_COOKIE` is not able to catch the "*set-cookies*"
2. What is the difference between `HTTP_QUERY_SET_COOKIE` and `HTTP_QUERY_COOKIE`?
3. What will be the impact if I use `HTTP_QUERY_COOKIE` to overcome this issue?

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: If this is [tag:c++] why the [tag:c] tag? does it apply?

Comment: This is common Wininet, any one c/c++ can work on these, that's why I tagged both c and C++. If I'm wrong do let me know I can remove C.

Comment: Ok, so if you did it intentionally it's fine.

Comment: No, it's just that some times the system suggests both tags although the problem is very specific to one of the two languages, I just wanted to know whether you was aware of the tag being there. If it was to evident that one of them did not apply I would have edited it.